# Unity-Firebase urls to signin or signup give error with restClient

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

Im learning Firebase with Unity and using the RestClient and while it worked well with just reading and writing to the database, in the authentication part Im stuck, I have only tested the signup part so far but it gives me error http unknown, I got the url from the reference docs in firebase site, here is the function that throws the error in case it helps but I assume I got the url wrong or something, Im open to any solution you give, thanks =) :

```
void signUpUser(string nombreusuario,string email, string password)
{
    string datosusuario="{\"email\":\""+email+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\",\"returnSecureToken\":true}";
    RestClient.Post<signresponse>("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=" + AuthKey, datosusuario).Then( ResponseHelper=>
    {
        localId = ResponseHelper.localId;
        idToken = ResponseHelper.idToken;
        nombre = nombreusuario;
        enviaBaseDatos(true);
    }).Catch(error=> 
    {
        Debug.Log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your endpoint is correctly typed, could be that you are using the wrong key? You should use the Web API Key of your Firebase project.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that and pointing what key is needed, I was lost first time i needed the key in the code, I verified again and authkey is correct, isnt there any pre-requisite I should have before authetication works? Im not sure if I miss something like I need to have an app configured there (currently there isnt any) or maybe that field thats says I should say where GCP resources are being stored, although I doubt other things are needed but just in case, any thing I need to do before the authentication is used?

Comment: well I asume that if you have the API key, you've enabled the Auth in firebase web console, right?

Comment: well, I have enabled email/password access, is that what you mean or is there other place where I have to enable authentication?

Comment: if you are not using the client SDK I think you are okey with that (tell me if the endpoints on my answer works for you pls)

Comment: thats strange, its not working with the endpoints you suggested, Im open to any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

So I've been digging and I think that documentation is partially wrong as it says that the endpoint is

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]
```

But It also says

> You can create a new email and password user by issuing an
> HTTP POST request to the Auth signupNewUser endpoint.

So the real endpoint is **signUpNewUser** instead of simply **signUp**!

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts: signUpNewUser?key=[API_KEY]
```

If this new endpoint does not work, try the version 3 of the endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signUpNewUser?key=[API_KEY]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to make it work, unfortunatelly these doesnt work, give same error of http unknown

Comment: I can pm you the whole code or the whole solution if you feel like checking it although I doubt the error is there